# How to insert a break tag after ) with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

The following is an output from an old CMS.

I'd like to insert

```
<br />
```

after

```
(<A HREF="edit-8.asp">Rediger dine kundeopplysninger</A>)
```

to become

```
(<A HREF="edit-8.asp">Rediger dine kundeopplysninger</A>)<br />
```

with jQuery.

```
<div id="system">
        <FORM ACTION="confirm-8.asp" METHOD="post" NAME="kassaForm">
        <TABLE BORDER="0" CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="2" WIDTH="100%">
         <TR>
          <TD CLASS="td-menu" COLSPAN="7">
            Kundeopplysninger
          </TD>
         </TR>
         <TR>
          <TD CLASS="td-main" COLSPAN="7">
            <BR>

            here any name (<A HREF="edit-8.asp">Rediger dine kundeopplysninger</A>)
            here any address<BR>
            <BR>
            2nd part of address<BR>
            <BR>
          </TD>

         </TR>
   more after here.....
```

Comment: What's variable and what's constant? will the URL in the link remain the same so one can select on that? Can you add id/class to the link? Even though the title suggests after ), wouldn't this be to general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/pYTgc/

```
var textNode = $('#system a[href$="edit-8.asp"]')[0].nextSibling​;

var newValue = textNode.nodeValue.replace(')', ')<br>'); 

$(textNode).replaceWith($('<span/>',{html:newValue}));
```

Or if you don't want the span there, you can unwrap it.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/pYTgc/1/

```
var textNode = $('#system a[href$="edit-8.asp"]')[0].nextSibling​;

var newValue = textNode.nodeValue.replace(')', ')<br>'); 

var span = $('<span/>',{html:newValue});

$(textNode).replaceWith( span );

span.children(':first').unwrap();
```